# Adding Two Click Handlers to 1 Function both using React hooks useState

Tags: reactjs, onclick, react-hooks, timeout, use-state

I have a button "Add to Cart" and I would like it to do two things when clicked. I want it to add an item to the cart and I also want it to Change the text to "added" for 1 second.

The problem is if I call onClick twice the second function overrides the first.

If I put both click handlers into 1 function and then call that in 1 single onClick the only the function adding things to the cart works.

Where am I going wrong?

```
const [variant, setVariant] = useState({ ...initialVariant })
const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1)

const {
    addVariantToCart,
    store: { client, adding },
  } = useContext(StoreContext)

const handleAddToCart = () => {
    addVariantToCart(productVariant.shopifyId, quantity)
  }

const text = "Add To Cart";
  const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState(text);
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setButtonText(text);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [buttonText])

const handleClick = () => {
    setButtonText("Added");
    handleAddToCart();
  }

return (
    <>
      <button
        className="add"
        type="submit"
        disabled={!available || adding}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Add to Cart
      </button>
      {!available && <p>This Product is out of Stock!</p>}
    </>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the `buttonText` inside the `button` as below, however, in your code you have used the hard text `Add to Cart`.

```
<button
        className="add"
        type="submit"
        disabled={!available || adding}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        {buttonText}
      </button>
```